# Not render error message bootstrap.widgets.TbAlert

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii

In `TBAlert.php if (Yii::app()->getComponent($this->userComponentId)->hasFlash($type))` this condition does not return true, but on live server its work ok

```
 <?php
 $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbAlert', array(
    'block'=>true, // display a larger alert block?
    'fade'=>true, // use transitions?
    'closeText'=>'&times;', // close link text - if set to false, no close link is displayed
 )); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

config/main.php

```
  'session' => array (
        'class' => 'CHttpSession',
        'sessionName' => 'brokerpad',
        'timeout' => 1440,
        'cookieMode' => 'allow',
        'cookieParams' => array(
            'path' => '/',
            'domain' => 'There are need to be place right domain',
            'httpOnly' => true,
        ),
    ),
```

'domain' => 'There are need to be place right domain',